# Is it possible to use dynamic templateurl from web with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

There are many examples using directives for creating dynamic forms with angularjs but i'm trying to do something different.

Currently i am using this in my js file:

```
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'my-customer.html'
  };
});
```

This is my-customer.html

```
  Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}
```

How to request a templateUrl from web like this:

```
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'http://www.garsoncepte.com/my-customer.php'
  };
});
```

Working example can be seen here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/U41xyBeeFXV7Osr7pI2Y?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd checked the [error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce/insecurl?p0=http:%2F%2Fwww.garsoncepte.com%2Fmy-customer.php) in the console it shows up as an untrusted URL because it's not on the same domain.

You can use `$sce` to allow the domain.

```
.directive('myCustomer', ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://www.garsoncepte.com/my-customer.php')
  };
}]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/QkQfdLjdmmqVRNyZsMEF?p=preview